# Fake service emails that are actually marketing emails

Tags: united-states, email-marketing, can-spam-act-of-2003

There is law in the US requiring email marketing lists to allow you to unsubscribe from them.

But emails that are part of providing a service seem to be exempt: you can't necessarily unsubscribe from your bill, or from the email stream wherein the company tells you that your personal information was leaked or that they have changed their web site address.

I get a lot of emails from major companies that *claim* to be service-related emails, but seem to me to be marketing emails.

For example, I once got an email that said "THIS IS A SERVICE-RELATED EMAIL" where the unsubscribe link would be, but the content of the email was an unsolicited advertisement for a survey some third party was conducting, on the subject of the class of services that the sending company was providing me.

How do you determine if an email that claims to be service related is actually too tangentially related to the mechanics of providing the service to rightly count? What are the penalties for misclassifying marketing emails as service-related emails, or for embedding excessive marketing content in legitimate service-related emails? Who is responsible for enforcing them? If I wanted some kind of injunctive relief to block a particular company from sending me misclassified emails, how would I go about getting it?